# Представление дерева значений в виде плоской карты

Tags: java, дерево, hashmap, treemap

Есть карта значений `Map<String, Object>`, элементами которой могут быть либо такие же карты, либо списки значений `List<Object>`, либо просто `String`. Элементами списков также могут быть `Map`, `List` или `String`. Глубина вложенности дерева не известна. Нужно представить эту структуру в виде плоской карты (`flatMap`) типа `Map<String, String>` с учетом вложенности. Например:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("1999", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("3", Arrays.asList("23", "24", "25"));
            put("4", Arrays.asList("1", "2", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("10", "42");
            }}));
        }});
        put("2001", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("11", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("7", Arrays.asList("23", "24", "25"));
                put("9", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
            }});
            put("12", "45");
        }});
    }};
    System.out.println(treeMap);
}
```

Карта значений:

```
{1999={3=[23, 24, 25], 4=[1, 2, {10=42}]},
 2001={11={7=[23, 24, 25], 9=[1, 2, 3]}, 12=45}}
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
{1999.3:1=23, 1999.3:2=24, 1999.3:3=25, 1999.4:1=1, 1999.4:2=2, 1999.4:3.10=42,
 2001.11.7:1=23, 2001.11.7:2=24, 2001.11.7:3=25,
 2001.11.9:1=1, 2001.11.9:2=2, 2001.11.9:3=3, 2001.12=45}
```

---

<sub>См. [Восстановление дерева значений по его плоской карте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149256/328896)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно рекурсивно обойти эту карту и обработать значения ее элементов в зависимости от их типа: `Map`, `List`, или `String`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("1999", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("3", Arrays.asList("23", "24", "25"));
            put("4", Arrays.asList("1", "2", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("10", "42");
            }}));
        }});
        put("2001", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("11", new TreeMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("7", Arrays.asList("23", "24", "25"));
                put("9", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
            }});
            put("12", "45");
        }});
    }};

    TreeMap<String, String> flatMap = new TreeMap<>();
    processMap("", treeMap, flatMap);

    System.out.println(treeMap);
    System.out.println(flatMap);
}
```

```java
private static void processMap(String prefix,
                               Map<String, Object> map,
                               Map<String, String> flatMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        processEntry(prefix, key, value, flatMap);
    }
}
```

```java
private static void processList(String prefix,
                                List<Object> list,
                                Map<String, String> flatMap) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String key = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        Object value = list.get(i);
        processEntry(prefix, key, value, flatMap);
    }
}
```

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void processEntry(String prefix,
                                 String key,
                                 Object value,
                                 Map<String, String> flatMap) {
    if (value instanceof Map) {
        processMap(prefix + key + ".", (Map<String, Object>) value, flatMap);
    } else if (value instanceof List) {
        processList(prefix + key + ":", (List<Object>) value, flatMap);
    } else if (value instanceof String) {
        flatMap.put(prefix + key, (String) value);
    }
}
```

---

Исходная карта:

```
{1999={3=[23, 24, 25], 4=[1, 2, {10=42}]},
 2001={11={7=[23, 24, 25], 9=[1, 2, 3]}, 12=45}}
```

Плоская карта:

```
{1999.3:1=23, 1999.3:2=24, 1999.3:3=25, 1999.4:1=1, 1999.4:2=2, 1999.4:3.10=42,
 2001.11.7:1=23, 2001.11.7:2=24, 2001.11.7:3=25,
 2001.11.9:1=1, 2001.11.9:2=2, 2001.11.9:3=3, 2001.12=45}
```

---

<sub>См. [Flatten nested Map containing with unknown level of nested Arrays and Maps recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733833/11141611)</sub>