# Восстановление дерева значений по его плоской карте

Tags: java, дерево, hashmap, treemap

Есть плоская карта (`flatMap`) значений типа `Map<String, String>`, по которой нужно восстановить исходное дерево значений. Элементами дерева могут быть либо карты значений `Map<String, Object>`, либо списки значений `List<Object>`, либо просто `String`. Глубина вложенности дерева не ограничена. Например:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, String> flatMap = new TreeMap<String, String>() {{
        put("1999.3:1", "23");
        put("1999.3:2", "24");
        put("1999.3:3", "25");
        put("1999.4:1", "1");
        put("1999.4:2", "2");
        put("1999.4:3.10", "42");
        put("2001.11.7:1", "23");
        put("2001.11.7:2", "24");
        put("2001.11.7:3", "25");
        put("2001.11.9:1", "1");
        put("2001.11.9:2", "2");
        put("2001.11.9:3", "3");
        put("2001.12", "45");
    }};
    System.out.println(flatMap);
}
```

Плоская карта:

```json
{1999.3:1=23, 1999.3:2=24, 1999.3:3=25, 1999.4:1=1, 1999.4:2=2, 1999.4:3.10=42,
 2001.11.7:1=23, 2001.11.7:2=24, 2001.11.7:3=25,
 2001.11.9:1=1, 2001.11.9:2=2, 2001.11.9:3=3, 2001.12=45}
```

Исходное дерево:

```json
{1999={3=[23, 24, 25], 4=[1, 2, {10=42}]},
 2001={11={7=[23, 24, 25], 9=[1, 2, 3]}, 12=45}}
```

---

Решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1149384/328896

---

<sub>См. [Представление дерева значений в виде плоской карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149206/328896)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбираем ключи плоской карты - восстанавливаем исходное дерево. Для каждого ключа слева направо ищем символы-разделители:

- Точка `.` - вложенный объект - это карта. Следующее за ней число - ключ в карте.
- Двоеточие `:` - вложенный объект - это лист. Следующее за ним число - порядок в листе.

Далее рекурсивно обрабатываем вложенные объекты, смещаясь вправо по ключу плоской карты:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, String> flatMap = new TreeMap<String, String>() {{
        put("1999.3:1", "23");
        put("1999.3:2", "24");
        put("1999.3:3", "25");
        put("1999.4:1", "1");
        put("1999.4:2", "2");
        put("1999.4:3.10", "42");
        put("2001.11.7:1", "23");
        put("2001.11.7:2", "24");
        put("2001.11.7:3", "25");
        put("2001.11.9:1", "1");
        put("2001.11.9:2", "2");
        put("2001.11.9:3", "3");
        put("2001.12", "45");
    }};
    TreeMap<String, Object> originalMap = new TreeMap<>();
    flatMap.forEach((key, value) -> processMap(key, value, originalMap));

    System.out.println(flatMap);
    System.out.println(originalMap);
}
```

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void processMap(String flatMapKey,
                               String flatMapValue,
                               Map<String, Object> map) {
    int dot = flatMapKey.indexOf('.');
    int colon = flatMapKey.indexOf(':');

    // nested map
    if (dot > -1 && (dot < colon || colon == -1)) {
        String key = flatMapKey.substring(0, dot);
        Object nestedMap = map.get(key);
        if (nestedMap == null) {
            map.put(key, new TreeMap<>());
        }
        nestedMap = map.get(key);
        processMap(flatMapKey.substring(dot + 1),
                flatMapValue, (Map<String, Object>) nestedMap);
    }
    // nested list
    else if (colon > -1 && (colon < dot || dot == -1)) {
        String key = flatMapKey.substring(0, colon);
        Object nestedList = map.get(key);
        if (nestedList == null) {
            map.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        nestedList = map.get(key);
        processList(flatMapKey.substring(colon + 1),
                flatMapValue, (List<Object>) nestedList);
    }
    // insert value
    else if (dot == colon) {
        map.put(flatMapKey, flatMapValue);
    }
}
```

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void processList(String flatMapKey,
                                String flatMapValue,
                                List<Object> list) {
    int dot = flatMapKey.indexOf('.');
    int colon = flatMapKey.indexOf(':');

    // nested map
    if (dot > -1 && (dot < colon || colon == -1)) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(flatMapKey.substring(0, dot));
        while (list.size() < index) {
            list.add(null);
        }
        Object nestedMap = list.get(index - 1);
        if (nestedMap == null) {
            list.set(index - 1, new TreeMap<>());
        }
        nestedMap = list.get(index - 1);
        processMap(flatMapKey.substring(dot + 1),
                flatMapValue, (Map<String, Object>) nestedMap);
    }
    // nested list
    else if (colon > -1 && (colon < dot || dot == -1)) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(flatMapKey.substring(0, colon));
        while (list.size() < index) {
            list.add(null);
        }
        Object nestedList = list.get(index - 1);
        if (nestedList == null) {
            list.set(index - 1, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        nestedList = list.get(index - 1);
        processList(flatMapKey.substring(colon + 1),
                flatMapValue, (List<Object>) nestedList);
    }
    // insert value
    else if (dot == colon) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(flatMapKey);
        while (list.size() < index) {
            list.add(null);
        }
        list.set(index - 1, flatMapValue);
    }
}
```

---

Плоская карта:

```
{1999.3:1=23, 1999.3:2=24, 1999.3:3=25, 1999.4:1=1, 1999.4:2=2, 1999.4:3.10=42,
 2001.11.7:1=23, 2001.11.7:2=24, 2001.11.7:3=25,
 2001.11.9:1=1, 2001.11.9:2=2, 2001.11.9:3=3, 2001.12=45}
```

Исходное дерево:

```
{1999={3=[23, 24, 25], 4=[1, 2, {10=42}]},
 2001={11={7=[23, 24, 25], 9=[1, 2, 3]}, 12=45}}
```

---

<sub>См. [Restoring a value tree from its flat map representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62811540/11141611)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, а чем смысл такой плоской карты. Раз уж конкатинируете строки, то тогда HashMap больше имеет смысла сделать, вместо словаря.

Ниже код для сборки оригинала из плоской карты.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TreeMap<String, String> flatMap = new TreeMap<String, String>() {{
        put("1999.3:1", "23");
        put("1999.3:2", "24");
        put("1999.3:3", "25");
        put("1999.4:1", "1");
        put("1999.4:2", "2");
        put("1999.4:3.10", "42");
        put("2001.11.7:1", "23");
        put("2001.11.7:2", "24");
        put("2001.11.7:3", "25");
        put("2001.11.9:1", "1");
        put("2001.11.9:2", "2");
        put("2001.11.9:3", "3");
        put("2001.12", "45");
    }};
    System.out.println(flatMap);
```

Код поиска оригинала ниже

```
    TreeMap<String, Object> original = new TreeMap<>();
    flatMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        String[] splitted = key.split("\\.");
        TreeMap<String, Object> node = original;
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length - 1; i++) {
            TreeMap<String, Object> child = null;
            if (node.containsKey(splitted[i])) child = (TreeMap<String, Object>) node.get(splitted[i]);
            else {
                child = new TreeMap<>();
                node.put(splitted[i], child);
            }
            node = child;
        }

        String lastSegment =splitted[splitted.length - 1];
        if (lastSegment.contains(":")){
            String[] lastSegmentSplitted =  lastSegment.split(":");
            ArrayList<String> array = null;
            if(node.containsKey(lastSegmentSplitted[0]))
                array = (ArrayList<String>) node.get(lastSegmentSplitted[0]);
            else{
                array = new ArrayList<>();
                node.put(lastSegmentSplitted[0], array);
            }
            array.add(value);;
        }
        else
            node.put(lastSegment, value);
    });
    System.out.println(original);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
{1999.3:1=23, 1999.3:2=24, 1999.3:3=25, 1999.4:1=1, 1999.4:2=2, 1999.4:3.10=42, 2001.11.7:1=23, 2001.11.7:2=24, 2001.11.7:3=25, 2001.11.9:1=1, 2001.11.9:2=2, 2001.11.9:3=3, 2001.12=45}

{1999={3=[23, 24, 25], 4=[1, 2], 4:3={10=42}}, 2001={11={7=[23, 24, 25], 9=[1, 2, 3]}, 12=45}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил добавить вторым ответом, так как подход тут совсем другой.

Можно из ваших данных сначала составить промежуточное дерево по типу Trie, где узел может быть как ключем, так и операцией, так и просто значением.

После построения Trie можно будет достаточно просто по нему пробежаться и восстановить ваше исходное дерево.

Пусть вас не смущает обилие кода, зато код достаточно структурированный и понятный + его легко адаптировать под новые типы данных.

Выглядит это так

```
class TrieNode
{
    private TreeMap<String, TrieNode> children = new TreeMap<>();
    private String value = null;
```

Методы для построения Trie

```
    public void add(String template, String value){
        ArrayList<String> splitted = splitString(template);
        add(splitted, 0, value);
    }

    private void add( ArrayList<String>  keys, int index, String value){
        if (index >= keys.size()){
            this.value = value;
            return;
        }
        String key = keys.get(index);
        if (children.containsKey(key)) children.get(key).add(keys, index+1, value);
        else{
            TrieNode node = new TrieNode();
            node.add(keys, index+1, value);
            children.put(key, node);
        }
    }
```

Тут мы разделим путь на части, то есть вот такой путь `1999.4:3.10` превратится в `1999`+`.`+`4`+`:`+`3`+`.`+`10`и каждый элемент пути будет отдельным узлом + ещё узел для значения

```
    private ArrayList<String> splitString(String str){
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c == '.' || c == ':'){
                str.substring(start, i);
                ret.add(str.substring(start, i));
                ret.add(str.substring(i, i+1));
                start = i+1;
            }
        }
        ret.add(str.substring(start));
        return ret;
    }
```

Метод для построения словаря. Он публичный так как мы знаем, что верхний уровень будет всегда словарем.

```
    public TreeMap<String, Object> buildMap(){
        TreeMap<String, Object> ret = new TreeMap<>();

        children.forEach((k,node)->{
            Object val = node.getObject();
            ret.put(k, val);
        });

        return ret;
    }
```

Метод для построения списка

```
    public ArrayList<Object> buildList(){
        ArrayList<Object> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        children.forEach((k,node)->{
            Object val = node.getObject();
            ret.add(val);
        });

        return ret;
    }
```

Метод для извлечения элемента словаря или списка. Результатом этого метода может быть словать, список или строка.

```
    private Object getObject(){
        if (this.value != null) return this.value;

        for (Map.Entry<String, TrieNode> item : children.entrySet()){
            if (item.getKey().equals(".")){
                return item.getValue().buildMap();
            }
            if (item.getKey().equals(":")){
                return item.getValue().buildList();
            }
        }
        return null; // до этой точки мы никогда не должны дойти
    }
}
```

Проверка выглядит так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, String> flatMap = new TreeMap<String, String>() {{
        put("1999.3:1", "23");
        put("1999.3:2", "24");
        put("1999.3:3", "25");
        put("1999.4:1", "1");
        put("1999.4:2", "2");
        put("1999.4:3.10", "42");
        put("2001.11.7:1", "23");
        put("2001.11.7:2", "24");
        put("2001.11.7:3", "25");
        put("2001.11.9:1", "1");
        put("2001.11.9:2", "2");
        put("2001.11.9:3", "3");
        put("2001.12", "45");
    }};
    System.out.println(flatMap);
    
    TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
    flatMap.forEach((key, value)->{
        root.add(key, value);
    });
    
    System.out.println(root.buildMap());
}
```

Вывод

```
{1999.3:1=23, 1999.3:2=24, 1999.3:3=25, 1999.4:1=1, 1999.4:2=2, 1999.4:3.10=42, 2001.11.7:1=23, 2001.11.7:2=24, 2001.11.7:3=25, 2001.11.9:1=1, 2001.11.9:2=2, 2001.11.9:3=3, 2001.12=45}

{1999={3=[23, 24, 25], 4=[1, 2, {10=42}]}, 2001={11={7=[23, 24, 25], 9=[1, 2, 3]}, 12=45}}
```