# Как преобразовать json response в массив/коллекцию объектов?

Tags: java, json, jackson, десериализация

Я могу преобразовать `response` в объект, используя:

```java
Object object = response.extract.as(Object.class);
```

Однако, как быть если `response` включает в себя массив объектов? т. е. `response` выглядит как-то так:

```
[
  "object": {
    *контент*
  },
  "object": {
    *контент*
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот:

это pojo-класс

```java
class Pojo {
    private String user;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

а это собственно код:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
        String jsonStr = "[\n"
                + "{\"user\": \"Вася\"},\n"
                + "{\"user\": \"Петя\"},\n"
                + "{\"user\": \"Маша\"}\n"
                + "]";
        // 1 способ - List<Pojo>
        List<Pojo> r1 = parseJson1(jsonStr);
        for (Pojo p : r1) {
            System.out.println(p.getUser());
        }
        // 2 способ - Pojo[]
        Pojo[] r2 = parseJson2(jsonStr);
        for (Pojo p : r2) {
            System.out.println(p.getUser());
        }
    }

    private static List<Pojo> parseJson1(String value) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Pojo> result = mapper.readValue(value, new TypeReference<List<Pojo>>() {
        });
        return result;
    }

    private static Pojo[] parseJson2(String value) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Pojo[] result = mapper.readValue(value, Pojo[].class);
        return result;
    }
}
```

ну и в pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

а вообще гуглится.)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) для преобразования строки `json` в какой-либо объект, в данном случае в `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Для примера возьмём `json` с массивом объектов:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Иван"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Фёдор"
  }
]
```

Зависимость Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Читаем строку `json` в объект `List` и выводим результат:

```java
String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Иван\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Фёдор\"}]";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Map<String, Object>> list = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);

System.out.println(list); // [{id=1, name=Иван}, {id=2, name=Фёдор}]
```

---

Можно просто читать строку `json` в объект:

```java
String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Иван\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Фёдор\"}]";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Object object = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);

System.out.println(object); // [{id=1, name=Иван}, {id=2, name=Фёдор}]
```

**НО:** при последующей обработке этого объекта потребуется приведение его к какому-либо типу (`Map`, `List` и т. д.).

---

Можно собственный алгоритм написать представления объекта в виде плоской карты:

- [«Представление дерева значений в виде плоской карты»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149206/328896)
- [«Восстановление дерева значений по его плоской карте»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149256/328896)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Items> items = jsonArrayToObjectList(
        "domain/ItemsArray.json",  Item.class);

public static <T> List<T> jsonArrayToObjectList(String jsonFileName, Class<T> tClass) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + jsonFileName);
    CollectionType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory()
        .constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, tClass);
    List<T> ts = mapper.readValue(file, listType);
    return ts;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]